# Why WebStorm launches Chrome browser when running in debug mode

Tags: intellij-idea, jasmine, karma-runner, webstorm

I want to debug Jasmine tests launched by Karma. In my `karma.conf.js` I have the following:

```
port: 9090,
urlRoot: '/',
autoWatch: false,
browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
```

So you can see that I specified `PhantomJS` as a browser to start. When I run tests in `Run` mode, `PhantomJS` is started. However, when I run tests in `Debug` mode, the Chrome browser is started and tests are actually executed in Chrome, instead of `PhantomJS`. Besides, I have these confusing log entries from Karma server:

```
13:42:36.239:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
13:42:37.987:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#MpnkVSEn2B33WWVTAAAA with id 88994634
```

Here is my configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is started as it's the only browser debugging is supported for. Debugging in PhantomJS is not supported; if you miss it, please vote for [WEB-6072](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6072)

Comment: thanks, so why does karma outputs that `PhantomJS` is started? is there any way to not launch `PhantomJS` when debugging, as Chrome will still be launched?

Comment: Actually PhantomJS is also started. When you debug karma tests, 2 browser instances are actually launched: karma launches a fresh profile of the browser specified in your configuration file, plus WebStorm runs Chrome browser with debug extension that is used for debugging

Comment: so are tests also executed in both browsers? how are they coordinated?

Comment: yes - tests are actually run in both browsers. It's not a problem, unless your intent is to debug errors specific to PhantomJS. In this case, the only solution is using custom launcher with debugging enabled (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher) and debug it remotely using another browser... doesn't work for me though - even with 'debug:true' debug switches are not passed to phantomjs

Comment: I see, thanks. One more question, where do messages come from that appear in [this `Test Run` tab](https://postimg.org/image/lljeheuvt/)?

Comment: sorry, I meant whether they come from Chrome or PhantomJS?